# Using cross domain JSONP requests with cookies?

Tags: ajax, cookies, internet-explorer-8, cross-domain, jsonp

My situation looks like this:

I use 2 domains.

In domain1 my users are logged in and there is a session cookie set for this domain.

In domain2 in my html I include a script tag with url pointing to an application that works on domain1 and which generates javascript. Like this:

```
<script src="http://domain1.com/jsactions"></script>
```

I'm wondering. When users enter domain2 can I assume that jsactions app (http://domain1.com/jsactions) will always recieve session cookie that was set for domain1 ? (Assuming ofcourse that it was previously created)

I'm wondering will this work in IE8+ and recent Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we've tested this approach recently. The JSONP request contains it's domain cookies (domain1 in your case).

And more over - if the JSONP response is setting a cookie in his header - that cookie will be included in the next roundtrip. We achieved crossdomain login scenario leveraging this behaviour (without redirectiong to domain1 at all).

Comment: What browsers did You use during tests ?

Comment: IIRC IE7+, Chrome (latest versions). Not sure about FireFox and Safari, but I believe that out testers checked them too.

Comment: I've just checked - this solution works in FireFox and does not work in Safari.

Comment: You're welcome :) There's a little chance that this method works in Safari and the error is actually in our app script.